# How can I re-enable MFA challenges when I login?

Tags: google-account, multi-factor-auth

I enabled MFA on my Google account because I wanted to protect it. Every time I logged-in, Google tried to get me to "Don't ask again on this device", and I un-checked the checkbox every single time (grumble).

Except once.

Now I do not get any more MFA challenges when logging-in from this computer.

How can I reset that setting so it asks me for my MFA credentials again each time I log in?

I tried on another browser and I got the challenge. Is this a browser-cookie that I can delete to re-enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to [myaccount.google.com/security](https://myaccount.google.com/security) (or [security.google.com](https://security.google.com)).

Click the **2-Step Verification** option.

You'll probably be prompted for your password to verify it's you.

Scroll to the bottom to **Devices you trust**. Choose "Revoke all". (Unfortunately, you can't change them piecemeal.)

Now you'll be prompted for the "second step" wherever you're trying to sign in.

Comment: Thanks! As a bonus... do you know any way to get rid of that stupid "Don't ask again on this computer" option?

Comment: I'm afraid not. That seems to be a permanent fixture.